# hostname in certificate didn't match:<>!=<> WSO2 APIM

Tags: https, wso2, ssl-certificate, wso2-api-manager, hostname

I have a https endpoint and I need to access it from wso2 API manager. (uses 1.10).I already added the certificate files to "client-truststore.jks" file. But now it gives an error as follows.

```
 hostname in certificate didn't match:<ip>!=<entry name>.
```

I have already updated the axis2.xml file as follows also.

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```

How can I solve this issue with WSO2 APIManager to access this https backend service

Comment: Have you set above AllowAll to listener or sender? You need to do this for HTTPS**Sender.

Comment: I set AllowAll under sender

Answer (score 1):

The CN of the certificate should match with the hostname of the URL. You get above error when they don't match.

Comment: is that means, entry name should be same as the ip address? because this API doesnt have any dns mapping

Comment: I don't think you can create a certificate with an IP for the CN. So you'll have to use a DNS mapping. In your dev environment, you can simply use `/etc/hosts` for this.

Comment: what do you mean by "you can simply use /etc/hosts for this"

Comment: You can set a DNS mapping in that file (if you run on linux/ubuntu)

Comment: ohh, but i'm working on windows. isnt there any other way of resolving this error?

Comment: Try this https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/10c/Local-DNS-modifications-on-Windows-etchosts-equi.html

Comment: You may also request a brand new cert after including that hostname/entity name or IP in cert's Subject Alternative Names list.